# Optimize the if condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to simplify this condition where a and b are booleans

```
!((a && b) || (!a && !b))
```

I have tried using the truth table generator, but I am not able to figure out the simplified version.

Comment: `if (!(a==b))`? or `if (a!=b)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be simplified as a `XOR` (exclusive or). It's equivalent to `(a && !b) || (!a && b)`.

In Java, it can be achieved as `a ^ b`

Comment: Would you please explain how you reached at (a && !b) || (!a && b)

Comment: @SunnyGupta An XOR means one must be true but not both. You can read more with proofs and examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 7):

You can simplify this in : `a!=b`,

---

Because, by equivalence :

```
!((a && b) || (!a && !b)) // not(both true or both false)
!(a==b)                   // not(both equals)
a!=b                      // different
```

---

And here is the table, which confirms that you `a` different of `b` :

```
 a\b  | true  | false
true  | false | true
false | true  | false
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify to either `if (!(a==b))` or `if (a!=b)`.

Your condition simplifies to "if a and b are both true (i.e., of equal state) or both false, then condition resolves to false". Or "if a is a different state to b, condition resolves to true".

Comment: @azro I had answered in the comments, because that's a bad habit of mine. Then put that into an answer.